# Cross product between columns of two matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Given two matrices [image] and [image] of dimensions a `D x N`, I want to compute [image]. Could you please suggest a vectorize way to do such calculation?

Thank you!

Comment: The way you have Y and X presented, they seem to be 1 dimensional vectors

Comment: @BradSolomon each y^(i) or x^(i) are column vectors of dimension D. Thanks!

Comment: Use a `numpy` examples, not mathematical notation.  That doesn't look like a mathematical cross product (see `np.cross`), it looks more like some sort of element wise product.  What is wrong with `Y*X`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to do it:

```
np.sum(x*y, axis=0)
```

Efficiency:

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(30, 400))
y = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(30, 400))

%timeit np.sum(x*y, axis=0)
# 38.4 µs ± 942 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit for i in range(len(x.T)): x[:, i].dot(y[:, i].T)   
# 1.01 ms ± 19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.diag(x.T.dot(y))
# 6.57 ms ± 248 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: `np.einsum('ij,ij->j', x, y, optimize=False)` is even faster.

Comment: Indeed it is. Didn't even know this existed. Thanks. `10 µs ± 25.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`